# Why did I need to specify 'ArrayValued' to get this integration to work in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a function which takes a scalar argument and outputs a scalar:

```
I1f = @(y) fundamentalSol([0, y], point);
function result = fundamentalSol(p, q)
    result = (1/(2*pi))*log(norm(p - q, 2));
end
```

However, I was not able to integrate this function as `integrate(I1f, 0, 1)` would pass a vector as `y` (why?).

```
User
>> integral(I1f, 0, 1)
Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation.

Error in G_and_H_check>fundamentalSol (line 12)
    result = (1/(2*pi))*log(norm(p - q));

Error in G_and_H_check>@(y)fundamentalSol([0,y],point) (line 3)
I1f = @(y) fundamentalSol([0, y], point);

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 87)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Related documentation
 
12      result = (1/(2*pi))*log(norm(p - q));
```

I fixed this by vectorizing everything

```
I1f = @(y) fundamentalSol([zeros(size(y))', y'], point);
I1 = integral(I1f, 0, 1, 'ArrayValued',true);
function result = fundamentalSol(p, q)
    result = (1/(2*pi))*log(vecnorm(p - q, 2, 2));
end
```

But I do not understand why it was necessary to do this and wonder if there was another way.

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#btbbkta-1-fun — it’s pretty clearly stated that the function must accept a vector, compute the result for each element in the vector, and output a vector with results. `integrate` saves lots of time this way.

Comment: When you set `arrayvalued` to true, it means the input will be a scalar, not a vector, and the result is some array (ie the function maps to multiple dimensions). You have a scalar function, so this is not necessary.

Comment: But you will have to rewrite your function to not use `norm`, since you are now computing a matrix norm. Use `vecnorm` instead.